# MS Excel is not showing tree map option in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to make a tree map chart in my Microsoft Excel 2010,
but it is not showing the option for a tree map chart in the Excel sheet. 
What can I do?

Comment: Refer to Official article the correct versions to user Treemap Chart in Excel are: **Excel for Office 365 Excel for Office 365 for Mac Excel 2019 Excel 2016 Excel 2019 for Mac Word 2016 Outlook 2016 PowerPoint 2016 Excel 2016 for Mac Excel for iPad Excel for iPhone Less** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-treemap-chart-in-office-dfe86d28-a610-4ef5-9b30-362d5c624b68

Comment: The [Office Support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-treemap-chart-in-office-dfe86d28-a610-4ef5-9b30-362d5c624b68) for “Create a treemap chart in Office” actually says “Excel for Office 365, Excel for Office 365 for Mac, Excel 2019, Excel 2016, Excel 2019 for Mac, Word 2016, Outlook 2016, PowerPoint 2016, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone”.   It's more readable with the commas (which are present on the linked page). … P.S. I don't know why they're listing Word, Outlook and PowerPoint on a page for a function that is, AFAICT, strictly an Excel function.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.excel2013.info/tree-map-chart) says that the tree map chart
is available only in Excel 2013 and 2016. 
[This one](http://www.exceltoxl.com/index.php?p=443) says that it is available only in Excel 2016,
but suggests that you can add it to older versions
by downloading the ["Tree Map App" from the Office Store](https://store.office.com/treemap-WA104067194.aspx?assetid=WA104067194).

P.S. I can confirm that it does *not* appear to be
in Excel 2013 (for Windows).